# VirtualBox Guest Additions for Linux Guest with kernel 5.0.5

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders, guest-additions

I'm trying to setup VirtualBox Additions for enabling shared folders between host and guest machine. The configuration is:

```
Host  : Windows 10 x64
Guest : Fedora Server 29.1.2 x64 [with updates up to kernel 5.0.5-200.fc29.x86-64]
VirtualBox version on host machine : 6.0.4
```

Instructions I'm following are:

```
sudo dnf -y upgrade
sudo dnf -y install gcc kernel-devel kernel-headers dkms make bzip2 perl kernel-$(uname -r) elfutils-libelf-devel libell binutils patch libgomp glibc-headers glibc-devel  automake
sudo dnf -y update kernel*
reboot
```

After restart and re-logging download and install the guest additions from iso image:

```
wget https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.4/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.4.iso
mkdir ./GuestInstaller
sudo mount ./VBoxGuestAdditions*.iso ./GuestInstaller
export KERN_DIR=/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)
sudo ./GuestInstaller/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
reboot
```

And, to have access to shared folders:

```
sudo usermod -aG vboxsf "$USER"
rm ./VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.4.iso
rm ./GuestInstaller -r
```

Problems occur at `sudo ./GuestInstaller/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` part. It Results in error `modprobe vboxsf failed`

Originally, I thought that VBoxAdditions 6.0.4 does not support kernel 5, but https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog supposes that it has to support.

Also, sometimes it is recommended to `export KERN_VER=$(uname -r)` instead of `export KERN_DIR=/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)` : didn't work.

How to fix it and install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.6 
This version resolve the build issue on kernel 5.0 or greater.

BUT! Since you are using Fedora. You can try installing Guest Additions via dnf package manager by typing 
`dnf install virtualbox-guest-additions` to install Guest Additions

Comment: It may looks weird and fun, but Fedora DVD doesn't even want to boot with VirtualBox 6.0.6

Comment: Works with VirtualBox 6.0.10, but not VB 6.0.6